# Understanding why Replication Distribution Agent stops

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

Let me preface this in that I'm working as an accidental DBA at the moment.

We have continuous transactional replication running.  For some reason the Distribution Agent stops with a message of "success", but I can't understand at all why it is stopping and from the logs I don't get much information.

Two questions.

1. Other than looking at the monitor does anyone have some good ideas as to where I can get a bit more detail?  I can do verbose logging to a file but the replication has lots of data and the files grow really big really fast.
2. Is there a way to have the Distribution Agent restart itself whenever it stops other than when I manually stop it?  Maybe adding an additional step to the Agent job?

Comment: How soon does the Agent stop after being started? Is that predictable? Could you perhaps turn on verbose logging temporarily just before the Agent is expected to stop, and turn it off immediately afterwards, thus collecting detailed information for later analysis?

Comment: It generally seems to be in the early hours of the morning that it stops.  Many hours after starting.  Unfortunately there isn't a real way to predict it otherwise I'd turn the output file logging on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as starting it...add a schedule that runs the job every minute. If the job is running, no issues.  If not, it will start.

can't help on question 1 with no additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the job step 2 of the distribution agent job and add -continuous at the end of the step. This will run the job continuously. Compare the distribution agent job with some other distribution agent job and see the difference in the script